# DB regex issue, to provide the constraint on DB column

Tags: sql, oracle

How to make the Column in Oracle DB which contains All **Numeral** values except certain:

I know the solution is based on some regex like to except all values we have the regex '*'.

Comment: Have you tried the function REGEXP_LIKE?

Comment: You can simply put a check condition on DB.

Comment: Make the column a `NUMBER` column then you don't need this hack. Do **not** store numbers in `varchar` columns, never.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE tt (
  b NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT special_numbers_chk CHECK (TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(to_char(b,'99999999999999999'), '[01254]*', '')) IS NULL)
);

INSERT INTO TT VALUES (122);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO TT VALUES (123);
ORA-02290: check constraint (XXXX_DVLP.SPECIAL_NUMBERS_CHK) violated

select * from tt;
   b
-------
  122
```

I use explicit conversion to char (specified the mask) to prevent sql injection and not to be depended from the DB environment, thus I need to get rid of spaces from the the conversion result to get null value, this is why I use `TRIM`.
P.S.: specify your sequence of numbers in the square brackets